# how do I compare two dates?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We would like to compare a date from the db with current date.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
'Obtain current date 

Dim curdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy")

'Now compare curdate with date from db called eventdate. Event date is of dateTime datatype.

If drv("eventdate").ToString = "" And Year(drv("eventdate").ToString) = curdate Then

 'Then do some processing
End if
```

When I run this code, I get following error:

**Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.**

Please help!

Thank you very much experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have either a null or empty value, also your comparisn is wrong, try:

```
If drv("eventdate").ToString <> "" Andalso Year(drv("eventdate").ToString) = curdate Then

 'Then do some processing
End if
```

Comment: thanks Jmoreno. very sorry for late response on this. I didn't get the email response. I am only seeing this now that I have come back for an additional question.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, no problem.  BTW, DBNull.Value.ToString returns the empty string, which is why I used that instead of directly checking for null (not sure what was in your table), generally you would want to just check for null.

Answer (score 3):

```
If Today.CompareTo(CDate(drv("eventdate")).Date) = 0 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

I'm making the assumption here that you only care about the day, and not the time. Otherwise, the odds of having a match within a given day would be about 1 in 2.5 million.

---

Based on the comment:

```
If Today.Year.CompareTo(CDate(drv("eventdate")).Year) = 0 Then
    'Do something
End If
```

or

```
If Today.Year = CDate(drv("eventdate")).Year Then
    'Do something
End if
```

And one more thing: it really sounds like this is a check that *should be done by your database*.  Make it part of the query that returns the results. This will be *much* faster, and it's where that kind of check belongs. All you'd need is add a check to your where clause like so:

```
Year(eventdate) = Year(current_timestamp)
```

Comment: thank you Joel for your kind response. We just want the year like 2011. We are basically trying to hide previous years data. So, in our current situation, we don't want to display any 2010 data. if event date is empty or event date = '2010' then display one thing. Otherwise,(the year is current year, show something else.

Comment: Thank you again Joel. I tried all your solutions and each one gives me this error which is similar to what I was getting: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid. I know no data is empty on the db.

Comment: Check again. If it's trying to convert from DBNull, you may not have any empty values in your table, but they're sure there in your query results. It's easy to write a query that would do that.

Answer (score 1):

If `drv` has an instance of DataReader then verify `DBNull`.

```
IF Not drv.IsDBNull(column_index_of_eventdate) Then
   ...
   If drv.GetDateTime(column_index).Year=Date.Now.Year Then
        ...
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you AVD. Great idea about verifying DBNull but I am not using an instance of DataReader. Any other ideas. Please also see my response to Joel's suggested solutions.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh What is the data type of eventDate? Use IsNothing to test the null. IF Not IsNothing(drv("colName")) then ...

Comment: The data type is datetime. I am about to test now. I will report back shortly. Thank you.

Comment: No love. I honestly thought this would be simple.